# save photo's original filename in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Here is how I save image in my image picker,my image picker uses the `defaultRepresentation`,kinda new to `AlAsset`.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask ,YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"oneSlotImages%u.png", i]];

ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [[info objectAtIndex: i] defaultRepresentation];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[rep fullResolutionImage]];

//----resize the images
image = [self imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:image toSize:CGSizeMake(256,256*image.size.height/image.size.width)];

//----fix image orientation
image  = [image fixSlotOrientation];

NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:YES];
```

My image picker works this way: When button is pressed, the camera roll pop-up,you pick the album you want, then you can pick images (multiple or single) then when done is pressed, it will save to `NSCachesDirectory`. In initial, when the button is pressed, you can still see the checkmark, but when app closes its gone. So I am thinking of just saving it via its original path.

How can I save my image by getting it from the original path, then store the picked one(multiple/single) in the `NSUserDefaults`, which later(after app was close from initial) I can use to reload the images again.

Answer (score 0):

Intially u add one NSMutableArray in NSUserDefault.

```
 [[NSUserDefault standardDefault] setObject:[NSMutableArray array] forKey:@"PickedImage"];
 [[NSUserDefault standardDefault] synchronize];
```

As such u get imageURL from didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:

```
NSURL *url = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
if([[NSUserDefault standardDefault] objectForKey:@"PickedImage"])
{
   NSMutableArray arrImages = [[NSUserDefault standardDefault] objectForKey:@"PickedImage"];
   [arrImages addObject:url];

   [[NSUserDefault standardDefault] setObject:arrImages forKey:@"PickedImage"];
 [[NSUserDefault standardDefault] synchronize]; 
}
```